# How can make visible outline to vector from multiple layers?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, illustration

[image]1st half is the object I made in illustrator  and second half is the only stroke of objects and now I want only visible object not the back layers one. Help me please

Comment: currently doing with the help of pathfinder's shape modes and taking too much time

Comment: paint the objects white? What is the final result you're expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Well, using pathfinder is a destructive way of doing it so stop it.

You can achieve the desired effect by adding the outline and add a white color as a background instead of those grays.

Other than this there's no way of having only outlines but see only the visible object without starting to cut your drawing. But adding white as the background is a clean and non-destructive way of achieving it.

Comment: Thanks but I need it for printing so It wont work if I print it with black color I need png with no color. again thanks.

Comment: @MayankKumar How would this affect your print? You don't need a transparent background png for print. That's cause normal printers don't print white so you are fine.